# How do I import SSL certifcate .pem file into JRE cacerts file on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, https, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have tried to use `keytool -importcert -alias (my cert alias) -file (cert file path.pem) -keystore (jre keystore path)` and I get an error that says my .pem file is not an x509 certificate.  I think it is because my .pem file is not formatted properly or because it contains both private key and certificate. Any suggestions?  My .pem file looks like the following:

```
Bag Attributes
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 
    friendlyName: 
    Microsoft CSP Name: 
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
   ...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHQzCCBiugAwIBAgIQDEtIx...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Give this tool a try. It might give you a little more info about the problem  https://keystore-explorer.org

Comment: Do you (does Mac) have really ancient Java? 6 and earlier did not handle other information preceding the (correct) PEM block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to import the certificate into my JRE cacerts file.  First I had to create a new .pem file with only the certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHQzCCBiugAwIBAgIQDEtIx...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then I had to copy the cacerts file into a new location, and then run the following code to import it:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias serveralias -file /Applications/certificate.pem -keystore /cacerts
```

After importing the certifcate I then copied the new cacerts file back into the JRE security folder, and success!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page on the PEM file format](http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/) Since your file contains references to Microsoft I suggest making sure the file uses Unix line endings (`\n`) instead of Windows line endings (`\r\n`)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I will try to split the .pem file into a privatekey.pem and certifcate.pem and then convert the line endings and I will get back to you to see if that worked.

Comment: Java can read PEM certs (and CRLs) with either or any kind of line delimiters, see `readOneBlock` in e.g. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/X509Factory.java or j6 used `BufferedReader` which ditto.

Comment: @dave I am using Java 8.  If I have the certificate on my machine can I read it as a file and import it into my cacerts file with java?  Or should I use the inputstream from the httpget and use readOneBlock ?

Comment: @TMO: you can't practically call `readOneBlock` directly; it's deep in the provider structure and gets called automatically when you use a `CertificateFactory` either in your code _or_ in keytool. j8 keytool should work as you had it in your Q and I don't know why it doesn't, unless there is some invisible damage/corruption in the file, which seems unlikely. If by 'httpget' you mean `HttpGet` in Apache httpclient, that obtains data from a server (or tries to) and has nothing to do with files on your machine, otherwise I don't know what you mean. ...

Comment: ... Given you presumably can't post the actual file with your cleartext privatekey, I don't know what else to say. Do you have or can you find or borrow any other system(s) you could test this file on?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have not been able to import the certificate into my cacerts file, however I was able to configure my CloseableHttpClient so that it will consume HTTPS URLS that do not have "valid" certificates. I Just used the following code when implementing my client:

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
    .loadTrustMaterial(null, ((certificate, authType) -> true)).build();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
```

I know that this is not the proper way to handle the situation but I'm not concerned about validating the certificate from the server I am communicating with in this specific instance.